# Bootstrap plugin pagination table not working with filter

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, filtering

I have this bootstrap pagination plugin that allows me to paginate the results in a table.

I also have a filter input box where you can type something and the table results are filtered. The problem is that the pagination plugin doesn't work with the filtering.

Any ideas how I can make the filter work with pagination that the filtered results are paginated based on the filter and not based on the original items in the table.

[Bootply example](http://bootply.com/93631)

In the example above you should try filter by ID number ex: 99 ...